# jquery ajax spring mvc3.0

Tags: jquery

Do i need any additional file other than jquery.js/jquery-min.jsd in order to enable the ajax jquery calls to the server?

Comment: @sje397 - why dont you make that an answer :)

Comment: problem is... Any normal jquery calls works fine if they r on client sode... but going to the server, doing something and coming back is not working... in fact the controller is not at all invoked... i have put up syso statements to check if controller is invoked... but no success....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The jquery script contains the `$.ajax` method.

Comment: That is a 'shorthand' method, that actually calls `$.ajax`, and it too is in the script.

Comment: yes... But it is not working.... the URL that we give in th getJSON call is any url which is matched in web.xml of the application and accordingly the function is invoked... am i correct?

Comment: It's not a jquery ajax problem. Examples of it's use are [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) ... but you should be able to debug the server just by hitting the url with your browser.